# eclipse drools plugin giving error "source not found" while debugging drl file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drools, rule-engine, drools-flow

when i try to debug drl file using eclipse drools plugin, it is not coming to debug point placed in drl rule file. It is giving error "source not found". But while executing, it works fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4SSD.png)

when i try to debug drl file using eclipse drools plugin, it is not coming to debug point placed in drl rule file. It is giving error "source not found".

But while executing, it works fine.

I was expecting the drools debugger to work same as any java debugger.

Comment: The debugger seems to work fine, only the source file is missing to show it to you. Please provide more information on why the debugger has paused and for what `Rule_Rule_2426257265.defaultConsequence(KnowledgeHelper, HL7, FactHandle) line: 7` stands for (is this some (dynamic?) generated code?). You tagged your question with `eclipse-plugin`. Please confirm that your code is part of an Eclipse plugin, otherwise remove the tag.